# Put object in nested object

Tags: javascript, json, object, format

Ik have to object and I want to combine those together the right way. I use this code to get them together:

```
return { record, voorraad: resultsr.filter(x => x != null) }
```

the output of this will be

```
{
   record:{
      _id:"5e8c226e62e43e41b59fe3d3",
      naam:"Dames fietsen"
   },
   voorraad:[
      {
         _id:"5e8cc9e059fcf75489ebac84",
         categorie:"5e8c226e62e43e41b59fe3d3",
         status:1
      }
   ]
}
```

But I like to have it this way

```
{
   record:{
      _id:"5e8c226e62e43e41b59fe3d3",
      naam:"Dames fietsen",
      voorraad:[
         {
            _id:"5e8cc9e059fcf75489ebac84",
            categorie:"5e8c226e62e43e41b59fe3d3",
            status:1
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Who can help me?

Comment: you can put the whole code?

Answer (score 0):

```js
// you have these
const record = {"_id":"5e8c226e62e43e41b59fe3d3", "naam":"Dames fietsen"};
 
const results = [
  {
    "_id":"5e8cc9e059fcf75489ebac84",
    "categorie":"5e8c226e62e43e41b59fe3d3",
    "status":1
  }
];
 
// so just do this 

record.voorraad = results.filter(x => x);
const returnValue = { record };

// and returnValue is what you want
console.log(returnValue);
```

Comment: his return is correct, something above is not correct

Comment: No, he is returning an object, within which he has the property `record`, and then he adds the `voorraad` property in alongside `record`. Whereas he needs `voorraad` to be within the `record` object, so he needs the `record.voorraad = results.filter(x => x);`

Answer (score 0):

this way ?

```js
var data = {
  "record":{
    "_id":"5e8c226e62e43e41b59fe3d3",
    "naam":"Dames fietsen"
  },
  "voorraad":[
    {
        "_id":"5e8cc9e059fcf75489ebac84",
        "categorie":"5e8c226e62e43e41b59fe3d3",
        "status":1
    }
  ]
}
data.record.voorraad = data.voorraad 
delete data.voorraad 

console.log( JSON.stringify( data, 0 ,2))
```

Answer (score 0):

uses destructuring:

```
const data = {
   record:{
      _id:"5e8c226e62e43e41b59fe3d3",
      naam:"Dames fietsen"
   },
   voorraad:[
      {
         _id:"5e8cc9e059fcf75489ebac84",
         categorie:"5e8c226e62e43e41b59fe3d3",
         status:1
      }
   ]
};

const { record, voorraad } = data;

const test = { ...record, voorraad: voorraad.filter(x => x != null) }

console.log(test);
```

Comment: It seems to me that OP wants "voorraad" inside the "record" object, which is not what you are doing